# Bash script works manually but not as cron job

Tags: bash, cron

I have a small bash script I'm trying to put together, basically it looks in a directory, moves all files starting with "pana" to a new directory while renaming them. The rename is the same for each file and each file is named in the same way originally.

Example directory and files:

```
/home/store/temp/pana-600-1586541564.jpg
/home/store/temp/pana-500-1586541563.jpg
/home/store/temp/son-600-1586541564.jpg
```

I want only the "pana" files processed and to end up in the following location/name.

```
/home/store/done/1586541564-pana-600-600.jpg
/home/store/done/1586541563-pana-500-500.jpg
```

The last part of the file name goes to the beginning and the middle part is duplicated on the end.

Here's what I have, which works as required if I manually run the .sh file,but does not work as a cron job

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /home/store/temp/pana*; do
    bn=$(basename $file)
    checkifempty=${#bn}
    if [[ "$checkifempty" = 1 ]]; then exit 
    fi

    IFS='-|\.' read var1 var2 var3 var4 <<< "$bn"

    newfile="$var3-$var1-$var2-$var2.$var4"

    mv $file /home/store/done/$newfile

done
exit
```

Cron entry (system log shows the script as being run but the files are never moved)

```
*/10 * * * * root sh /home/scripts/movefiles.sh
```

Comment: Can you show the crontab entry?

Comment: Added cron entry to post - it runs every 10 minutes.

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Get rid of `sh`. You can't use bash extensions like `<<<`.

Comment: @egtrev: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: adding bash instead seems to have fixed it. Thanks.